# Undefined control sequence $\Lambda \in \mathb

Tags: fonts

distributions, where `$\Lambda \in \mathb{Z}^{+}$` is a security par...

Please guide me to overcome this error

Thanks

Comment: try with `\mathbb{Z}`

Answer (score 7):

1. There is a typo (`\mathbb` is the correct command).
2. You must have the `amsfonts` package added in the preamble.

This example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\Lambda \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE.** The compiler reports the command it did not recognise. If you are running pdflatex or whatever from the command prompt, you are likely to have seen this message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 $\Lambda \in \mathb
                       {Z}^{+}$
```

Look at the second line. `l.4` means that the unexpected thing is in the fourth line of the input file, and the last thing in the line before the break is the culprit (in this case, `\mathb`). Please examine the error message: if there is a typo, it will always say “Undefined control sequence” and then put the unrecognised command before the break. Please look at that and try to figure it out for yourself at first.